# Version conflict

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

I'm getting version conflicts on UUID. Basically, `cached_network_image` depends on `uuid 2.0.0` while the `socket packages` depend on `uuid 1.0.3`

```
uuid:  ^1.0.3
cached_network_image: ^0.6.2
socket_io: ^0.9.0+1
socket_io_common: any
socket_io_common_client: ^0.10.0``
```

Because `cached_network_image ^0.6.2` depends on`flutter_cache_manager ^0.3.1` which depends on `uuid ^2.0.0`, `cached_network_image ^0.6.2` requires `uuid ^2.0.0`.

So, because `<PROJECT NAME>` depends on both `uuid ^1.0.3` and `cached_network_image ^0.6.2`, version solving failed.

I tried using UUID ^1.0.3 to include this version and 2.0.0 but to no avail.

Tried contacting the authors of the latter packages to upgrade their UUID dependency to the latest one but they haven't replied yet. I also opened an issue to their repo.

Here are some links:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/socket_io

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/socket_io_common

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/socket_io_common_client

https://github.com/rikulo/socket.io-client-dart

Comment: Check it out: [Flutter 2 upgrade - Flutter version solving failed error](https://medium.com/@pratikbutani/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is replace the version numbers with any like below:

```
uuid:  any
cached_network_image: any
socket_io: any
socket_io_common: any
socket_io_common_client: any
```

Let `Pub's version constraint resolver` do it's work .
Once version conflict is resolved, you can look at the `pubspec.lock` file and update the corresponding version numbers in your `pubspec.yaml` file .

This should unblock you from this problem.
You can try upgrading your version, once the corresponding plugins update their dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Unfortunately this produced **a lot** more issues than the initial scenario.

gist of the error stack here:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kevinespaldon/adb3891292191187fd76395e457dfa30/raw/ecbd2ef633c5591a3b63c477d3f4c1191f2bb1a0/dart%2520error

Answer (score 0):

Had the author update the UUID package. Closing this thread!